# How to remove\clear model state error when controller return FileStreamResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, modelstate

How do I remove the error message I added in `if` scope when system flow to `else` scope?

```
if (_data.emVendorOrdersFromSuppliers.Count <= 0)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "There are no data to download for the selected year and month!");
    return View(viewModelDownloadEMVendorData);
}
else
{
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = GenerateEmVendorOrdersWorkBook(_data);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    workbook.Write(memoryStream);
    string saveAsFileName = "EmVendor.xls";
    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", saveAsFileName);
}
```

I tried:

```
ModelState[""].Errors.Clear();
```

or

```
ModelState["assignedKey"].Errors.Clear();
```

prompt error "Object reference not set to an instance...".

View page still show `if` error message after user successfully get the file, that's why I want to remove the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your model errors by using

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Comment: @Pop "View page still show if error message after user successfully get the file"
if you return file from controller page doesn't get updated.
so if you have rendered error on client view, you should manually change page, reload or something like that (js).